# Nodemon server is not working with NPM start command

Tags: node.js

working with Node project and following is My `server.js` file as well

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

dotenv .config({path:'config.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT||8080

//log request
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

//set view engine
app.set("view engine","ejs")
//app.set("views",path.resolve(__dirname,"views/ejs"))

//load assets
app.use('/css',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/css")))
app.use('/img',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/img")))
app.use('/js',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"assets/js")))


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(PORT,()=>{console.log('Server is Running on http://localhost:${PORT}')});
```

but when I try with `npm start` command my server url `localhost:8080` is not working but cmd running smoothly. url localhost:8080 is displaying as `Unable to connect` how could I fix this problem here?
**Terminal output**

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is Running on http://localhost:${PORT}
GET / 200 694 - 28.832 ms
GET / 304 - - 4.226 ms
GET /favicon.ico 404 150 - 5.648 ms
```

and I have config.env file as following
`PORT=3000`

Comment: You didn't write the template literals of JavaScript. Instead of Trying code: console.log('Server is Running on localhost:${PORT}'); Try code: console.log(``Server is Running on localhost:${PORT}``); And then, check port number.

Comment: You can't see the backtick in the comments above. Change to a backtick instead of single quotes.

Comment: Yes, definitely. First, add backtick instead of a single quote in the `Server is Running on....` line.

Comment: still not fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

kindly check what is written inside `package.json` file's `"scripts"` section. In which `"start"` should be there with the right command. Then your `npm start` will execute the command written over there.

**Note**: Nodemon should be globally installed. `npm install -g nodemon`

Example:

```
{
    //.....
    "scripts": {
        "start" : "nodemon server.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: my script is like this `"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },`

Comment: Share the terminal output after you run `npm start`. I want to see more specific errors. Also, share what is port inside `.env` file.

Comment: Have you check with `localhost:3000`. because you wrote the logic for changing the port to 8080 if and only if `.env` does not have any value in `PORT`.

Comment: localhost:3000 is working but not other pages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run on localhost:8080, modify to `const PORT = 8080;`.

Because port: 3000 is set in the config.env file, port: 8080 cannot be run.

Modify `port` setting in the config.env file or change `PORT` value in the server.js file.